# How to get not duplicated three digits randomly using function in Python

Tags: python-3.7

```
import random
def get_random_number():
     return random.randrange(100, 1000)

def get_not_duplicated_random_number():
  //enter your code here
    result = None
    return result
```

I need to implement this part using the `get_random_number()` function

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the 3 digits from every number and compare them. Something like this:

```
import math
import random

def get_random_number():
    return random.randrange(100, 1000)

numbers = [];
for i in range(0,3):
    number = get_random_number();
    e = math.floor(number/100);
    d = math.floor((number-e*100)/10);
    m = math.floor((number-e*100-d*10));


    while (e == d or d == m or m == e):
        number = get_random_number();
        e = math.floor(number/100);
        d = math.floor((number-e*100)/10);
        m = math.floor((number-e*100-d*10));


    numbers.append(number)

print(numbers)
```

Comment: three random digits without duplication include 234, 567, 480, 237, 912, but NOT 588, 393, 999, 466, 222 and returns only numbers

Comment: I think you don't understand my question, get_random_number() function gives us three random digits like 678 which is OK, but sometimes if it gives 677, which has double 7(sevens) and 777 which has triple(sevens) that is NOT OK, thank you for your help

Comment: Variables `e,d,m` contain the digits. While those digits are the same the number generating function is called.

Comment: Ahhh I made a typo there. One last time edited. Please upvote and accept my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want no repeated digits, then you want to select 3 digits without replacement.  This is made slightly more difficult because `0` cannot be your first digit:

```
from random import sample
from string import digits
from itertools import chain

digits = set(digits)
first = sample(digits, 1)
rest = sample(digits.difference(first), 2)
result = int(''.join(chain(first, rest)))
```

(You can make this faster by doing everything with `range(10)` rather than `string.digits`, but I felt this was more illustrative)

Comment: Ok, if you use set, which removes duplicates and  it causes the loss of one or two of three integers

Comment: @IhtiyorAbduazizov No, I'm just using sets to make removing items a little easier.  The important part is thinking about this problem as selecting from the set of digits with certain rules, rather than selecting from a range of numbers.